# **error: Result from function call is not a proper array of floats.**

Tags: python, scipy

```
i = 1
                
        t_HS_1  = t_5 + del_t_pinch
        t_13    = t_2 + del_t_pinch

        for i in range(10000):   
    
            def f(z):
                m_w_HPx, t_z = z
                f1 = m_h*Cp_h*(t_12 - t_z) - m_w_HPx*(h_7 - h_6)
                f2 = m_h*Cp_h*(t_z - t_HS_1) - m_w_HPx*(h_6 - h_5)
                return [f1,f2]
    
            x = fsolve(f,[100.,10.])
    
            m_w_HPx = x[0]
            t_z     = x[1]
            del_t   = [t_12 - t_7, t_z - t_6, t_HS_1 - t_5]
            t_HS_1  = t_HS_1 + 0.1

            if t_z - t_6 >= del_t_pinch:
                break
        j = 1
        for j in range(10000):   
            def f(z):
                m_w_x, t_y = z
                f1 = m_h*Cp_h*(t_HS_1 - t_y) - (m_w_x - m_w_HPx)*(h_4 - h_3)
                f2 = m_h*Cp_h*(t_y - t_13) - m_w_x*(h_3 - h_2)
                return [f1,f2]
    
            x = fsolve(f,[100,10])
                            
            m_w_x = x[0]
            t_y   = x[1]
            del_t = [t_HS_1 - t_4, t_y - t_3, t_13 - t_2]
            t_13   = t_13 + 0.1
                                
            if min(del_t) >= del_t_pinch:
                break
```

The code mentioned above results in an error like following ---

File `F:/My Programming/Python/ORC/chineese_paper_dual_pressure.py`, line 584, in pl_optima
x = fsolve(f,[100.,10.])

File `C:\Users\Asus\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\minpack.py`, line 147, in fsolve
res = _root_hybr(func, x0, args, jac=fprime, **options)

File `C:\Users\Asus\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\minpack.py`, line 225, in _root_hybr
ml, mu, epsfcn, factor, diag)

**error: Result from function call is not a proper array of floats.**

**Similar code works well in another places I previously used. What is the probable cause of error?**

Comment: A clean copy-n-paste of the error traceback might help us.  Showing the `fsolve` call in a simple case that we can copy-n-paste and run would also help - at least if you want us to run some diagnostics.  In the current code the `fsolve` calls are embedded in loops, so it's hard to guess what the inputs and outs are.  I also recommend doing a `f(np.array([100.,10.]))`, and checking the result against the `fsolve` docs.

Comment: The short version of the last comment: run your own diagnostic calculations/prints; don't expect us to "run" the code in our heads.